# cakephp error. Connection to database ...not ...: Access denied for user 'my_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: database, cakephp, default, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to start CakePHP. I made bookmarker and tested by command `bin\cake server`. It showed one error as connection to database could not be established:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES).`

I read the `config/app.default.php` file. It says there is a database `my_app` and another database `test_myapp` with some users. I can not find these databases in phymyadmin in xampp. Am I supposed to create the named databases and users manually? I thought CakePHP should create these automatically. Or should I give names of databases etc. which I like and create the same.I'm using xampp with windows 7 and am very new to CakePHP.

Comment: test_myapp is a test database setup by cakephp itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cake will not create the database or database user for you. You need to create them yourself and then match these database credentials into the db config file. Your datasource in `app/Config/app.php` file should look something similar to:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'my_db_user',
        'password' => 'my_db_user_password',
        'database' => 'cake_database_name',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
    ]
],
```

In this example you would have to create a database named: **cake_database_name**, and then add a database user named **my_db_user** with the password of **my_db_user_password**.

Comment: Thanks a lot McWayWeb, specially for the detailed way you answered. You make it very simple. You judged my level of ability accurately and gave a simple explaination!

Comment: I added a database for cake and another for test. I created a user also with a few priviliages. I changed the values in config.app.php as per the 2 databases I created. Still bin\cake server command gives the error Access denied for user 'my_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES). It should not even use the name 'my_app' since I changed it in config/app.php but it persists. Please help.

Comment: I also make 4 tables in the first database as advised by cake docs.

Comment: I got it now. I was editing the wrong app.php. I now edited the higher app.php and it is working nicely. It connects to the database. I am so happy. Thanks  a lot.

Comment: Which app.php file did you change?

Answer (score 3):

- Edit **Config/app_local.php** file instead of *Config/app.php* with your database connection parameters, i.e. host, username, password, database name. This will solve the problem.
- *Be sure to create same database first and providing enough privileges to same user you're writing in app_local.php file.*

Answer (score 1):

**See in  Mysql.php:**

class Mysql extends Driver
{

```
use MysqlDialectTrait;
use PDODriverTrait;

/**
 * Base configuration settings for MySQL driver
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_baseConfig = [
    'persistent' => true,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'cake',
    'port' => '3306',
    'flags' => [],
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
    'timezone' => null,
    'init' => [],
];
```

**Then in app.php write**

```
            'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '', 
        'database' => 'cake',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,

...],
```

**In phpMyAdmin 
create cake database.
It's all.**

Answer (score 1):

Edit **Config/app_local.php** file with your database connection parameters. You will find host, username, password, database name their.

**don't edit config/app.php** with database connection parameters.

**Your problem will be now solved**

*CakePHP 4.x*

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_app'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES).

Reason:

> No user id: "my_app" with password: "secret" [or any other] set in config/app.php
>   file.

Solution:

> In case of WAMP, go to phpmyadmin page, then we can select cake_cms
>   database -> privilage-> create user id and password, same as in config
>   file config/app.php, refresh the http://localhost:8765/ page.
>   it should now show
>
> CakePHP is able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp, make sure port is uncomment in Datasources and 'port' => '3308'

Answer (score 0):

[image]I solved this problem by checking port at phpmyadmin top
and uncommit below line in app_local.php

```
'port' => '3308',
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP3.9.3,app_local.php,'username`=>'root','password'=>'','database' => 'db name'

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it