# cakephp version 4 fresh install database not connecting

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

```
'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '000000',
            'database' => 'cakephp',
            'encoding' => 'utf8mb4',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
```

my database in phpmyadmin in xampp is ok.

But stil the cakephp homepage says

```
CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692914/cakephp-4-0-database-configuration/59694485**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced this issue and solved it by adding database configuration in `config/app_local.php`

As per Cakephp documentation:

> The application skeleton features a `config/app.php` file which should
>   contain configuration that doesn’t vary across the various
>   environments your application is deployed in.
>
> The `config/app_local.php`
>   file should contain the configuration data that varies between
>   environments and should be managed by configuration management, or
>   your deployment tooling

Reference: 
[CAKEPHP -> Configuration -> Configuring your Application](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/configuration.html#configuring-your-application)